# Ubuntu 20.04: VLC player not quitting

Tags: vlc-media-player

The vlc player is such a great tool, however it is not working properly on my Ubuntu 20.4 Laptop.
Specs: `AMD® Ryzen 7 pro 3700u w/ radeon vega mobile gfx × 8` 
The issue:
When I start the player, it is playing properly.
But as soon as I close it, the icon stays at the top right corner, and there is no way to play videos with this instance.

I can still open new instances with the vlc player, but then further icons are occurring.

[image]

A screen record can be seen here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/VLC/comments/hi4guw/ubuntu_2004_vlc_does_not_reopen_once_its_closed/

Any ideas?
My current solution is to I kill the process in the terminal

Comment: `pkill` may come in handy ... but on my system I am able to click these icons on the panel and quit the instances individually. But I agree that it's annoying. Question: are you using the snap or the Debian package (`dpkg -l|grep vlc` vs. `snap list|grep vlc`)?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I installed it from the ubuntu software store, so I guess it is snap.
Writing the two commands that you posted both give me outputs in the terminal

Comment: I have the same problem with VLC, but another additional part, how is your laptop power consumption? For me with AMD ryzen, its very high.

Comment: [Related bug posted on VLC forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=149762&start=25)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250477/vlc-is-still-running-even-i-closed-it-already-how-to-i-close-it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to `Tools` > `Preferences`, then `Inputs/Codec` tab.

Change **Hardware Accelerated decoding** to something other than `Automatic` or `VDPAU`.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1871949/comments/8

Comment: Solved my issue.

Comment: worked for me by changing Hardware Accelerated Decoding to "Disable".  No performance issues.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: it solves earlier, but i update kernel and vlc. I can't find those option anymore

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo: I'm on updated 20.04 with kernel 5.10.18 and I still can see this option.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha strange i am on v [3.0.12.1](https://gist.github.com/sukrosono/851b4f0875bafe20806f04ed3007a89e) and doesn't see that options. am I on a newer v than you?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had a similar issue with the VLC media player. I found that the closed player will only stay around and remain unusable when I close it with the window close button (usually a red circle in the top right corner with an “X”). If I instead close the player with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or via “Media” → “Quit”, then the player is closed properly.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually logged a bug report with VLC and the response was very good and it turned out to be how I closed VLC that was the problem. I always clicked on the "X" in the top right hand corner to close VLC. When I repeated this action the VLC icon on the status bar would not disappear and VLC was unresponsive. I had to reboot Ubuntu to get rid of the icon on the status bar.

THE SOLUTION: Close the current song / video by clicking on the "Stop playback" at the bottom left *then* use the "X" at the top right or click on "Media" at the top left and click on "Quit".

I tested the "solution" by repeating it several times and it worked perfectly every time.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem (Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.1), but i could fix it with:
disable `Tools > Preferences > Interface > Playlist an Instances > Use only one instance when started from file manager`

aside from that, there is also:
enable `Tools > Preferences > Interface > Playlist an Instances > Allow only one instance`
disable `Tools > Preferences > Interface > Look and feel > Show systray icon`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow vlc is exit properly when I do quit with ctrl + q.
My answer is maybe just relevant to vlc that installed via snap.

The external attempt to kill all vlc instance is using:

```
killall -9 $(pgrep vlc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper permanent solution is present at https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/vlc-closes-fix.html

Which I found from **forkirara's answer** at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250477/vlc-is-still-running-even-i-closed-it-already-how-to-i-close-it

The copy-pasted answer is :

1. Delete folder /home/your user/.config/vlc
2. Open vlc
3. Open Preferences dialog, click on the Videos tab or button at the
   top. Then change our output to OpenGL video output.
4. Then click on the Input / Codecs tab or button at the top. Then
   change Hardware-accelerated decoding to Disable and then click the
   Save button. Now close VLC Media Player.

Works for me as well !

Answer (score -1):

I just disabled the systray icon in Tools->Preferences->Interface tab.

Comment: and that process still running!